# Variable name is an integer in ActionScript 3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I am pulling .json info from weatherunderground into Flash CC. After I parse the data I am left with the following variables:

[image: Flash Variables]

I am trying to get to the "conditions" variable. But I can't get there because of the integer/number "0"  How do I format it?

This is my code:

```
function completeHandler(event: Event): void 
{
    var loader1: URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);

    var data1: Object = JSON.parse(loader1.data);

    trace(data1.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday.0.conditions);
}
```

This works for variables that don't have an integer in their path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forecastday` is an array, which you can see in the Value column (`[] (@...`). The JSON is just telling you what is contained in each element of the array, so just use `data1.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].conditions`, or loop through for each day.